# extract word before first dot from url in nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server, devops

I use **nginx**

Assume that url **`"hello.test.example.com"`**, **hello** example of dynamically subdomain,
how can i get the word before the first dot in **nginx** config ??
the result must be "**hello**" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>[^.]+)\.test\.example\.com$;
    ...
}
```

As of this configuration, the first part of subdomain name will be available as `$subdomain` variable value.

Comment: when nginx reload >> Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

Comment: Sorry, missed a semicolon after the regex.

Comment: $subdomain empty string !!

Comment: I can't help you further unless I'll see how do you use `$subdomain` variable in your configuration. There can be some caveats if you'd use it in conjunction with the `if` directive.

Comment: if (-f $file) {
        return 302 http://$subdomain.test2.example.com/;
  }

Comment: Sorry, missing another sign in regex :) Try an updated one

Comment: this condition  not working correctly

Comment: server_name ~^(?<subdomain>[^.]+)\.example\.com$;

        set $file /home/ubuntu/html/files/$host;
        if (-f $file) {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://$subdomain.example2.com/$1;
        }

Comment: can you help me ?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What you are trying to achieve?Assuming the `Host` HTTP header in your request is `test.example.com`, you are trying to check the `/home/ubuntu/html/files/test.example.com` file existence. Using `-f` condition neither directory nor symlink would pass this check. Next, you are trying to generate an HTTP redirect to `http://test.example2.com` preserving the request URI? What type of redirect do you want to generate? A permanent `HTTP 301` or a temporary `HTTP 302`? Can your request be the `POST` request?

Comment: I have two servers, when the file already exists in this path /home/ubuntu/html/files, then any request from subdomain.example.com redirect automatically to example2, this running but not every time !

Comment: Try adding the `redirect` flag to your rewrite directive. Alternatively you can try `return 302 http://$subdomain.example2.com$request_uri` instead of `rewrite ... redirect` directive.

Comment: same result !!!

Comment: Can you help me ?